# Global Sass variable (Vue 3, Vite) get: [sass] Undefined variable

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

[image]

Hi!! I'm trying to migrate a Vue application from Webpack to Vite. But, I'm starting with this small project first.

Basically, I'm getting the error: '[sass] Undefined variable' when trying to use the variable $globalColor in the App.vue component. As you see in the code that I'm sharing, I added the css preprocessor configuration in Vite, but with no success. I read several posts and everybody says that's the solution.

Eventually, I would like to have Bootstrap mixins and variables globally because I don't want to import Bootstrap into every component like I'm doing in the App.vue component.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '~bootstrap': resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')
    }
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/scss/global.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**src/main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.scss'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**src/style.scss**

```
@import "@/scss/_vars";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**src/scss/_var.scss**

```
$my-padding-top: 64px;
```

**src/scss/global.scss**

```
$globalColor: pink;
```

src/App.vue

```
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <div class="mt-5">
    aaaaaa
    <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
      <img src="/vite.svg" class="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://vuejs.org/" target="_blank">
      <img src="./assets/vue.svg" class="logo vue" alt="Vue logo" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <HelloWorld msg="Vite + Vue" />
</template>

<style lang="sass" type="text/sass" scoped>
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
@import "@/scss/_vars"

div
  color: $globalColor
  padding-top: $my-padding-top

@include media-breakpoint-down(lg)
  body
    background-color: $primary
</style>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the import in `vite.config.js` without using the `@` alias? `@import "./src/scss/global.scss";`

Comment: Hi @paddyfields . Yes, the global.scss is imported correctly when vite compiles (without using the $globalColor variable basically)

Comment: I am having this exact same issue except I am trying to use a mixin from my globals file and the error is that the mixin is undefined.

Comment: Hi @Sawces . I also have problems with mixins. I tried to import mixins from Bootstrap globally without success. The only way that I achieved to import them was to do it directly in the component, but I don't want to do that, that's why I wanted them globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I cannot mix Scss and Sass.

Basically in the Vite config, I have:

```
...
scss: {
    additionalData: `@import "@/scss/global.scss";`
}
...
```

And in the App.vue I have:

```
<style lang="sass" type="text/sass" scoped>
...
```

If I change the preprocessor to Sass or vice versa, I can use the $globalVariable that I have defined.